# Main class not found when trying to dockerize a Java/Gradle project

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I have a Java project using gradle and my objectif is to dockerize it, I'm not very familiar with gradle so my problem can be just a misunderstanding from me.

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./build/libs/project.jar /app/project.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "project.jar"]
```

My project contains differents modules not linked to my problem I only let the 'application' module part, because this is where my main class is present.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1' apply false
    id 'org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert' version '3.3.2' apply false
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.0.4' apply false
    id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' version '0.39.0'
    id 'net.researchgate.release' version '2.8.1' apply false
    id 'java-library'
    id 'jacoco'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'path.to.my.class.MyMainClass'
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '6.8.3'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}

subprojects {
    group = 'fr.mnhn'

    buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '2.6.1'
            myBatisVersion = '2.2.0'
            guavaVersion = '31.0.1-jre'
            dbToolsVersion = '1.1.7'
            apacheCommonsVersion = '2.8.0'
            lombokVersion = '1.18.22'
            umsMavenRepo = '/'      // Nexus Repository Manager URL
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url = "$umsMavenRepo/maven-public"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.spotless'
    apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports { mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion") }
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled false
            csv.enabled false
            html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacoco/html")
        }
    }

    spotless {
        java {
            googleJavaFormat()
        }
        format 'misc', {
            target '**/*.gradle', 'application/src/**/*.yml'
            trimTrailingWhitespace()
            indentWithSpaces(2)
            endWithNewline()
        }
        scala {
            scalafmt()
        }
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    release {
        git {
            pushToRemote = ''
        }
    }
}

project(':application') {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    configurations {
        developmentOnly
        runtimeClasspath {
            extendsFrom developmentOnly
        }
        compile {
            exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
        implementation "org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:$myBatisVersion"
        //implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-jdbc:5.3.12)
        implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.0'
        implementation "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
        implementation "commons-io:commons-io:$apacheCommonsVersion"
        implementation "fr.mnhn:db-tools:${dbToolsVersion}"
        implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.13'
        runtimeOnly 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.0.1'
        runtimeOnly 'com.oracle:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1'
        runtimeOnly 'de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:2.5.4'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.6.0'
        compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
        annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform {
            excludeTags 'web'
        }
    }

    task integrationTest(type: Test, group: 'verification') {
        useJUnitPlatform {
            includeTags 'web'
        }
    }
    check.dependsOn(integrationTest)

    springBoot {
        buildInfo()
    }
}
```

This is MyMainClass.java :

```
package path.to.my.class;

import org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = "path.to.my.class",
    exclude = {
      DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
      DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
      MybatisAutoConfiguration.class
    })
public class MyMainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyMainClass.class, args);
  }
}
```

And this is how my project is structured :

```
 - project
   - build.gradle
   - Dockerfile
   - build
     - libs
       - project.jar
   - application
     - src
       - main
         - java
          - path.to.my.class
           - MyMainClass.Java
```

When I build my project with `./gradlew build`, I don't have any problem.
After that I build my docker image and then run it, this is where I have a problem I got this error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.path.to.my.class.MyMainClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.main.java.path.to.my.class.MyMainClass
```

I have the same error, when I'm trying to start my project with `java -jar build/libs/project.jar`

I don't get why my main class can't be found, I tried putting the complete path from the root of my project, but that didn't work too.

EDIT : The project.jar contains one directory "META-INF" that have a file "MANIFEST.MF" :

```
Main-Class: path.to.my.class.MyMainClass
```

Comment: The error sounds like a general problem building the jar file, and it seems like you've confirmed it's not specific to Docker.  Can you remove the Docker details from the question, but add in a minimum complete extract of the `build.gradle`?

Comment: The reason it is empty is that there are no source files in src/main/java and gradle doesn't know about application/src/main/java. You can either make a submodule `application` or modify the java source location in build.gradle.

Comment: Before fiddling around with Gradle and Docker, you should have a solid understanding about Java packages (so what package is declared in your MyMainClass? This should answer the proper value for "Main-Class:")

Comment: The package declared in MyMainClass is "path.to.my.class". And `path.to.my.class.MyMainClass` for "Main-Class" does not work too.

Comment: Please show the code for `MyMainClass`. In particular, what is the `package` statement at the top? Does it match what you put in the `java.manifest` section in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have added to the body of my question the code of `MyMainClass`, as you can see the `package` statement match what I have in my `java.manifest` section.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
attributes 'Main-Class': 'path.to.my.class.MyMainClass'
```

src/main/java is just the location of the source code, that is not reflected in the jar file, only the folders below are.

Comment: I suggest you try to extract the jar file, then take a look at the folder structure and the manifest file.

Comment: I just tried it, and it didn't work. My build.gradle file is not in the module "application", and I can't move it because I have other modules in that project.

Comment: If you have other modules anyway, then just add a application/build.gradle and include it in settings.gradle

Comment: With another build.gradle in the application module, it seems like the jar{manifest{}} part is ignored. I'm sure the file is taken into account because if I put in it something already present in my main build.gradle I've got an error about it.
By defining the Main-Class in application/build.gradle, i have the error `no main manifest attribute, in project.jar`

Comment: @Gollo When you say "I just tried it, and it didn't work.", what do you mean? What did you try and what were the results? We can only help you if you provide some details. This step has nothing to do with gradle, nor do you need to do anything with the `build.gradle` file. Use the `jar` tool from the JDK to extract the contents of the jar to view them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this replie was about the answer of Erik to change the Main-class attributes. I sent this replie at the same time Erik talk about the jar file. I have added to body of the subject the content of my jar file.

Comment: @Gollo My mistake. So the jar file doesn't contain `path/to/my/class/MyMainClass.class`? If so, then there is a problem with your build and gradle. This has nothing to do with docker.